Pulling data from another Excel Sheet using a VARIABLE as the sheet name
How do you do it using a variable sheet name? The following command will pull the sheet name, but I need to insert it into the IF command.
=MID(CELL("filename"),FIND("\]",CELL("filename"))+1,11)

I want to use the above command in this IF statement below.
=IF('**651 Floor 0**'!A12=""," ",'**651 Floor 0**'!A12)

=IF(MID(CELL("filename"),FIND("]",CELL("filename"))+1,11)!A8=""," ",MID(CELL("filename"),FIND("]",CELL("filename"))+1,11)!A8)

=IF('MID(CELL("filename"),FIND("]",CELL("filename"))+1,11')!A8=""," ",'MID(CELL("filename"),FIND("]",CELL("filename"))+1,11')!A8)


Look into INDIRECT

Cells on the active sheet can be referred to without the name of the sheet: =A1

As Scott Craner mentioned, use INDIRECT. INDIRECT allows you to dynamically create any reference you would normally hardcode. Say you have the name of the sheet you want to reference in B1, then use the following:
=IF(INDIRECT(B1 & "!A12")=""," ",INDIRECT(B1 & "!A12"))

This will allow you to reference any sheet by a value stored in B1, and then access the value at A12 within that sheet. You must have the sheet name stored in a known/calculable location or variable so that you may use it in the INDIRECT function.
